# checksum vs originalChecksums in artifactory API response

Tags: artifactory

Can someone explain difference betwwen checksums field and originalChecksums for files in artifactory(REST API calls) (version 3.x)? I get whole lot of bug details when I google, but I'm not why both the fields exist and what is the need for them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tools, such as Maven, which are aware of the Artifact checksums, Artifactory keeps a record of the original checksum reported by the tool.
This can happen in one of 2 ways:

1. When Maven (or other tools) deploys an artifacts and its matching sha1 checksum file
2. When the artifacts is retrieved from an external repository

The checksums field contains the checksum which are calculated by Artifactory. Artifactory 3.x is calculating sha1 and md5 checksums. Artifactory 4.x also calculates sha2 checksums. Artifactory is using those checksums when required. The originalChecksum is just kept as a record.

The original checksums were mostly important when public Maven repositories contained a large amount of wrong checksum files. Today it is not a common situation.

If the deploying tool is not providing a checksum or provides it in a non standrad way, Artifactory will not have an originalchecksum.

Comment: Thanks drorb :) What if someother tool that is not aware of artifactory is used to depoloy an artifact (if its possible)?

Comment: I updated the answer with some additional information